# set values after sending mail

Tags: email, for-loop, checkbox, google-sheets, automation

I want the script to send an email to those mail addresses where unchecked boxes are in the row - This works fine. But I want the value of the checkbox to be set “True” after the mails were sent.

My Problem is that I need the last for-loop to stop after all checkboxes are checked. In other words: The last loop has to stop when an empty cell appears.

First of all I manually trigger the script - later I will start it with the help of a button in the menu (function onOpen...)

Appreciate any help – thanks a lot!

Check out the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nR7Ox0bj93Rn58sldu9zYVpABjgI8u-guFQIjPpQ_pA/edit?usp=sharing) and the code below:

---

```
    function sendmail() {

      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var r = s.getRange('C:C');                     //Checkboxes
      var v = r.getValues();    
       for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
       if(v[0,i]=='false') { 
        var range = ss.getRange("A1:D4");
        var UserData = range.getValues();
        var UserData = range.getValues();
        var row = UserData[i];
        var name = row[0];
        var email = row[1];

        MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Test", "Hello " + name + ", This is an email");   
        var response = ui.alert("mail was send to ", ui.ButtonSet.OK);

    }
         for (k=1; k < 20; k++) {               //loop which has to stop
         s.getRange(k, 3).setValue("True");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet. Would you edit your question to explain how `sendmail()` is triggered.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your quick response! Hope the edited version helps.

Comment: In your loop, try `for(var i=v.length-1;i>0;i--) `

Comment: @Tedinoz thank you for your suggestion - I very much welcome the help! unfortunately it does not work. The whole column gets the value "TRUE".

Comment: Refer the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of major changes in your script.

1. The condition for the loop is wrong. Change to:
   `for(var i=v.length-1;i>0;i--)`
2. The UI response is missing the recipient name. Change to:
   `var response = ui.alert("mail was send to "+name, ui.ButtonSet.OK);`
3. `var UserData = range.getValues();` is declared twice: delete one row
4. Immediately after the UI alert (and still within the IF loop), add a line to update the checkbox: `UserData[i][2] = true;`
5. Simplify the updating of checkboxes.

   - Delete the existing lines:
     `for (k=1; k < 20; k++) {`
     `s.getRange(k, 3).setValue("True");`
     `}`
   - Substitute:
     `range.setValues(UserData)`

Revised Script

---

```
function sosendmail() {

      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var r = s.getRange('C:C');                     //Checkboxes
      var v = r.getValues();    
       for(var i=v.length-1;i>0;i--) 
       if(v[0,i]=='false') { 

        var range = ss.getRange("A1:D4");
        var UserData = range.getValues();       
        var row = UserData[i];
        var name = row[0];
        var email = row[1];
        // MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Test", "Hello " + name + ", This is an email"); 
        Logger.log("mail sent")
        var response = ui.alert("mail was send to "+name, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
        UserData[i][2] = true;

    }

    range.setValues(UserData)
}
```

---

Alternative Script

The following script is offered as an alternative. It avoids multiple `getRange()/getValue` statements and uses a more conventional top-down loop.

```
function sosendmail01() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // get the number of rows (Alast)
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var AlastRow = Avals.filter(String).length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of rows  = "+AlastRow)

  // get the data range
  var r = s.getRange(2, 1, AlastRow, 3);// get all the data
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+r.getA1Notation())
  var v = r.getValues(); // get the data 

  // loop through the rows of data 
  for (var i = 0;i<AlastRow;i++){
    if (v[i][2] != false) { 
      // the checkbox is ticked Don't sent an email
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", name = "+v[i][0]+" - the checkbox is ticked");

    } else{
      // the checkbox IS NOT ticked - send an email
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", name = "+v[i][0]+" checkbox = "+v[i][2]+" - the checkbox is NOT ticked");
      var name = v[i][0];
      var email = v[i][1];

      //MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Test", "Hello " + name + ", This is an email");   
      Logger.log("DEBUG: mail sent to "+name+" at "+email)
      var response = ui.alert("mail was send to "+name, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      v[i][2] = true;
  }

}
  r.setValues(v);

}
```